# Secure web service requests

Tags: android, web-services, security

I need to make requests to a web service via android application.
The webservice can be designed as needed.

It seems to me that no matter which approach I will choose, someone who wants to hack it, will just need to reverse engineer My android appliaction code (which isn`t very hard) and
could see exactly what I do, wheather I encrypt the data, use hardcoded Password or any other solution for that matter.

Is there a solution which will be 100% secure?

Comment: Take a look at this. I think they're asking the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320937/securing-communication-from-android-to-a-web-service

Comment: I did read this answer prior to asking the question - but I don`t think it solves the issue of reverse engineering the app.

Comment: you can encrypt the data, store the hash of the key in db, and encrypt the db. this should be harder to hack

Comment: There is no 100% secure, never will be. If your user (i.e. app) needs to access it, you have to have both the lock and key on the device at some point. Your only option is to make it *harder* to deter the less dedicated attackers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no 100% secure, all you can do is make things harder for your attacker. Things you can consider:

- Encryption - Passing your requests over encrypted channels will stop
  basic sniffing (this can be countered with MITM)
- Obfuscation - Make your intent harder to understand when they *do* decompile your app

The second part to this is mitigation - the ability to notice when your app has been compromised and deal with it. A typical way of handling this is to assign a unique token to each client on first run then pass this as an argument on each call to your service.

This way if somebody decompiles your app and figures out how to call your service you can at least start monitoring where the abusive requests are coming from and also monitor for suspicious behaviour (i.e. multiple requests from the same key in a short period across different IP addresses). From there you can start blocking keys.

Comment: See this http://shabbirdhangot.wordpress.com/2014/07/12/secure-web-service-url-in-android/

Answer (score 2):

You're worried about "hacking ", but the base of any security discussion is defining the risk.

What are you trying to protect against?

For example, are you trying to protect against an attacker to read someone else's connection to the server?

A simple and secure solution for this scenario would be to use an asymmetric key exchange for your symmetric encryption keys, or use an existing protocol that does this (e.g. HTTPS). embed the server's private key (or certificate if using HTTPS) to also defend against man-in-the-middle attacks. Reverse-engineering your app won't help an attacker here.