# Android 2-way SSL implementation

Tags: android

I could not find any info on this. The best is 1 way server side SSL implementation in Android.

Can this be done? Any reference, I can refer to? I could not find any info on the Android Developer website too.

Comment: What is 2-way SSL? Are you talking about encryption or about authentication or about something else?

Comment: @VictorRonin I meant HTTPS.

Comment: Actually, my emphasis was on the word __2-way__. Are you talking about 2-way authentication (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v5r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.itim.infocenter.doc%2Fcpt%2Fcpt_ic_security_ssl_authent2way.html)?

Comment: @VictorRonin Yes, referring to this. I trying to implement this in Android.

Comment: Please take a look at these question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064810/using-client-server-certificates-for-two-way-authentication-ssl-socket-on-androi

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431801/securing-a-web-service-so-it-can-only-be-called-by-a-specific-android-applicatio

Comment: maybe this material is what you want http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/https-with-client-certificates-on/